# some listing pages are not displaying images properly

Tags: magento-1.9, category, layout, product-list

some of our listing pages are not displaying properly here

[image]

means,

1. Images are not displaying properly
2. `Device Design Category Sort By` options are not displaying.
3. On right side , "Now accepting paypal" is displaying.

But all other pages are working fine like here
[image]

we have same configuration for both pages. `Page Layout : No layout updates`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove below style

`width: 1000px;`

from /skin/frontend/rwd/<custom-theme>/css/styles.css at line 8226.

**EDIT**

Go to admin > Catalog > Manage Category > Sony Xperia T3 > Custom Design > Page Layout

Set it to one column.

Comment: i tried that, but that wil expand the images, but still `Device Design Category Sort By` will not display also paypal logo will still display

Comment: updated answer check it

Comment: sorry, still same issue.

Answer (score 2):

it was problem with Anchor category, once we set the Anchor category to "YES" , its working fine